# How to record Lync 2013 call in one to one meeting not a group meeting?

Tags: recording, lync-2013

When using Lync, I can record the group meeting call (with a group of at least 3 attendees); though, I can NOT recrod the call if I call one-to-one with another person.

So my question is how can I record on-to-one Lync meeting call?

Can record with group call >= 3 attendees

[image]

Cannot record with one-on-one call

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Lync 2013, click the menu "Meet Now". It opens a conversation window, to which you can drag and drop people. This window shows the Recording options.

Answer (score 1):

The recording happens in a conference only, so you will need to create a Lync meeting (conference) and send the invite to another user. When both of you join the meeting by clicking "Join Lync Meeting" from Outlook invite, it will treat it as conference, and would let you record.

Comment: in Lync 2010 it works also if you are alone in the conference, just it need to be a conference, not only a discussion; but I can't check it in Lync 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [old article](http://ucken.blogspot.de/2010/11/lync-call-recording.html) that explains some limitations of Lync 2010 and server side settings. It seems it's still valid for Lync 2013